# Trying to check if file_exists in an IF statement

Tags: codeigniter

i am trying to check if a file exists, however it is in codeigniter behind /application/views folder.

Is there a way to check for this file OR do I need to move it outside the /application/ folder?

any help would be appreciated?

I am calling the filename from the controller like so:

```
    public function event() {   

    $data['main_content'] = 'event';

    $this->load->view('template', $data);

    }
```

then in the file 'template.php' is where I am making the IF statement for IF file_exists then display that file otherwise do nothing:

```
<?php

$filename = $main_content;
$exists = file_exists('application/views/scripts' . $main_content);

var_dump($exists); // just for testing

$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view($main_content);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');

if ($exists){
    $this->load->view('scripts/'.$main_content.''); 
} else{ }
```

?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$filename = 'whatever';
$exists = file_exists('application/views/' . $filename);

var_dump($exists); // just for testing
```

Alternatively, try:

```
file_exists(realpath(APPPATH . '/views/' . $filename)));
```

I just tested both ways, both in a controller and a view, and they are working properly.

Comment: i got bool(false) but the page does exist ...?

Comment: @user2763616 Where are you trying it from (e.g. a controller, view, etc.)?

Comment: im trying it from a template file i created in /application/views/template.php in this file I am checking to see "if file_exists" and if so, then display $this->load->view($file);  I pass the filename of the variable from the controller with $data['main-content'] = filename;

Comment: @user2763616 I edited my answer, have a look. If that still doesn't work, test if `var_dumo(realpath(APPPATH . '/views/' . $filename)));` produces the path you're expecting.

Comment: still getting FALSE result.  For $Filename if I'm passing a variable do I need to add the extension (.php)?  In the file template.php, I am passing in $main_content, which is defined in my controller, so my path is "/application/views/scripts/event"  do I need to add .php?

Comment: I got it to work.  Thank you.  The issue was I was missing the '.php'.  once I added, it output bool(true).  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2763616 You're welcome. Yes, it needs the full file name, including its extension (if any). By the way, since you accepted the answer, you can also upvote it as well. :)